# Python Write To File Error: Lists

Tags: python, list, tuples, items, writetofile

I've been trying to write two tuple lists I've created to a txt file called WorldSeriesWinnersND.txt HOWEVER, though no error messages come up when the program is run, the txt file remains unchanged. I have tried several different ways to get the tuples written to the file, two of which I will illustrate below. Please let me know what I'm missing.

```
def createFileNoDuplicates(winnersND, winsTuple):

    wins_file = open('WorldSeriesWinnersND.txt', 'w')

    wins_file.write("\n".join(winnersND))        

    wins_file.write("\n".join(winsTuple))

    wins_file.close()
```

and

```
def createFileNoDuplicates(winnersND, winsTuple):

    wins_file = open('WorldSeriesWinnersND.txt', 'w')

    for item in winsTuple:
        wins_file.write('%s\n' % item)

    wins_file.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right text file?

Comment: You could start by using with: It shigly recommended when using files: http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/

Comment: are you sure you're actually calling the functions you've listed above?

Comment: I'm not sure whats going on ```In [5]: createFileNoDuplicates(None, (1,2,3,4,5))

In [6]: cat WorldSeriesWinnersND.txt
1
2
3
4
5
``` works for me

Comment: Hey all, thank you so much, for some reason, I deleted the txt file and tried again, and it worked! Lordy :P thank you for taking the time to look at this question